# How to modify a grammar to fit SLR(1)?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, grammar

I have this grammar which has a conflict in the SLR(1) parsing table:

```
E -> E + E
E -> a
```

Generated automata by JFLAP:

[image: automata]

Generated table by JFLAP (conflict with S3):
[image: table]

I have a task to modify the grammar itself to fit SLR(1) but I don't seem to find anything about it in the web, maybe the question is poorly asked or my google search skills need an improvement, I will be happy for some explanation for a better understanding.

Comment: You could google `eliminate left recursion`.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError solving left recursion is only needed in ```LL(1)```, ```SLR(1)``` doesn't have a conflict with it.

Edit: plus why would I go to top-down parser rules when it's needed to be a bottom-up one?

Comment: The grammar is ambiguous. You need to fix that m

Comment: @ImSo3K As rici says, the grammar is ambiguous. This is a common issue with binary operators defined in this way. You can have two potential derivations for something like a + a + a; (a + a) + a OR a + (a + a) - depending on whether you reduce or shift respectively (when in state 4 and seeing a '+' token). These kinds of conflicts aren't a practical hindrance in parser generation tools where you can codify this choice with associativity declarations but are a problem in your context whereby we consider a grammar not to fit a certain parsing formalism/algorithm if a conflict arises at all.